# InflateException with FloatingActionButton from Official Design Library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, inflate-exception, floating-action-button, android-support-design

I am getting a bug using the official `FloatingActionButton` from Google's support design library.

Here is my LogCat.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:655)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at ---.---.com.---.SubCategoryFragment.onCreateView(SubCategoryFragment.java:47)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:968)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1014)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:910)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:901)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:90)
at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate(LayerDrawable.java:932)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate(RippleDrawable.java:891)
at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:16324)
at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:16193)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$201(FloatingActionButton.java:56)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$1.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:118)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java:75)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:131)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:79)
... 27 more
```

The only line that points to my app is where it inflates the `xml` file, and the line in that file which is my `FloatingActionButton`.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFABSubCat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
        android:src="@drawable/add_icon"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4sp" />
```

Extra info:

Here is my app theme:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MBTIAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeNoActionBar" parent="MBTIAppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Yes, I am using an `AppCompatActivity`.

I noticed I am using an older version of appcompat:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
```

This seems to be up to date:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Also,

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Now, I do set the Visibility to `GONE` in some case for my FAB, but this is after it inflates so that can't be the issue.

Now, this works with my 5.1 device, but the users who have issues have 5.0.

Is this a known bug or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: `android:backgroundTint` could be troublesome on devices pre lollipop. Use `app:backgroundTint` instead. I cant't point out any issues for 5.0 though.

Comment: @MarkusRubey  Thanks.  That is worth changing.  I changed that and updated my appCompat library in Gradle and checking to see if this fixes the issue.  I do know it never crashed on a pre 5.0 device or emulator for me when I was testing even though I had that tint in.  But not all devices are created equal...

Comment: @MarkusRubey  I believe it was your comment that fixed this problem.  A problem with tinting which I think is compatible for 5.1 up unless you use `app` like you say.  Feel free to add it as the answer.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+` added support for tinting widgets on devices running pre android 5.1 (API Level 21). To make use of it make sure you extend or set the `AppCompat` Theme and use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint`.

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

Comment: Note that backgroundTint support was added in API 21 (Android 5.0):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#backgroundTint

So according to the spec, you should be able to use backgroundTint in Android 5.0 without the support library. In practice, it seems to crash, and you need to use the support library to get it working. I just thought I would mention this for anyone else confused why an API labelled as v21 in the dev documentation doesn't actually work until v22; it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 50):

Just replace

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
...
...
android:backgroundTint
/>
```

to

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
...
...
app:backgroundTint
/>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" namespace!

Comment: problem in my case was setting background with android:background attribute. Replace with app:backgroundTint solved the problem

Answer (score 13):

If you're using a `VectorDrawableCompat` (Vector asset) you should use:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/x"
```

instead of:

```
android:src="@drawable/x"
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and tried different solution. But the one that worked for me was to ensure that appcompat and design support library versions are the same. 
for example:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just change `android` to `app`:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
```

To:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get this message is if you accidentally specified different versions of the appcompat library in different modules. This is likely to happen when you create a new module, since Android Studio defaults to the most current version.

For a tidy way of managing this in multi-module projects, see: [In Gradle, how do I declare common dependencies in a single place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547170/in-gradle-how-do-i-declare-common-dependencies-in-a-single-place)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was because of the false configuration of activity theme. problem was solved after i changed app theme to Theme.AppCompat.xxx.