# Floating Action Button causing error and crashing application

Tags: java, android

When using the floating action button, my Android application crashes and throws an error. When I remove it, my application runs successfully, but I'd rather use the floating action button if I can.

This is my complete error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.supriya.hithere/com.example.supriya.hithere.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
     at com.example.supriya.hithere.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
     at com.example.supriya.hithere.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02005f a=-1 r=0x7f02005f}
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2103)
     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
     at android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:36)
     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:114)
     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
     at com.example.supriya.hithere.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: Post code xml and build.gradle !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InflateException with FloatingActionButton from Official Design Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870443/inflateexception-with-floatingactionbutton-from-official-design-library)

Comment: Please post your full code or Logcat where you are getting the error?@Snehal

Comment: i have add the complete logcat hope you could get the problem and help me. Thanks.......

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Were you using the Facebook SDK with version higher than 4.17.0 ? (included)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you are using `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`, and AppCompat theme.

```
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

If you are using any attributes like `backgroundTint` or `borderWidth` for the FAB, make sure you are using `app` namespace.

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/accent_color"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Check that the version of appcompat and design library are same in your build.gradle app. Or atleast the version of design library is not older than that of appcompat.

For example:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This one work for me Finally

```html
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```