# InflateException - Floating Action Button

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, floating-action-button

I am getting this error my application

> Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

I search error on the internet I try everything but I did not see my mistake.I will appreciate any help.

This is my xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/bg_call_incoming"
android:orientation="vertical">
           ...
           <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton//line80 
            android:id="@+id/fabCallButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_white_24dp"
            app:tint="#004684"
            app:rippleColor="@color/ripple_color"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
            ...
```

Build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs',include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
}
```

Loggat:

> 05-08 10:54:58.380 4808-4808/io.nitro.uzmaniaraexpert E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: io.nitro.uzmaniaraexpert, PID: 4808
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.nitro.uzmaniaraexpert/io.nitro.uzmaniaraexpert.DenemeAnimation}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>           at io.nitro.uzmaniaraexpert.DenemeAnimation.onCreate(DenemeAnimation.java:56)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>           at io.nitro.uzmaniaraexpert.DenemeAnimation.onCreate(DenemeAnimation.java:56) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>           at io.nitro.uzmaniaraexpert.DenemeAnimation.onCreate(DenemeAnimation.java:56) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080074
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1401)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
>           at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
>           at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:184)
>           at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:158)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>           at io.nitro.uzmaniaraexpert.DenemeAnimation.onCreate(DenemeAnimation.java:56) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

Comment: Following this from the error log -`Binary XML file line #80` - What do you have in line 80 in the xml file?

Comment: I edit my question, I delete unneccesary images on xml to keep it short to question error gets after adding floating button.

Comment: Maybe it's this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37020077/4255978, Or this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30895974/4255978

Comment: probably you are getting this error because you are using vector image in FAB Button

Comment: I try changing image and backgroundTint but it did not work I realize in styles file I get  Theme  symbol cannot resolved error. If I remove fab its work but. symbol cannot resolved error not disappear. I try clean gradle,delete and redownload but I am still getting Theme cannot resolved error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
app:tint="#004684"
```

with

```
app:backgroundTint="#004684"
```