# Java android FloatingActionButton set image and color

Tags: java, android

I want to do this : FloatingActionButton  I want to set an Image and change color to : GREEN . I try do this :

```
 <com.smok.maps.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ikona2"
            android:tint="@color/green"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/mapview"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />
```

But this floatingActionButton still is red

Comment: You are changing the `tint`, aren't you supposed to change the background(tint)?

Comment: which gradel are you using?

Comment: try `app:backgroundTint="@color/green"`

Comment: @farhana i use : .build:gradle:2.3.3

Comment: I mean for FloatingActionButton which Github library , you are using

Comment: @ZUNJAE I did this but It doesn't work I have  :                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference

Comment: @RahulMandaliya Whhen I did this I see this :                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference

Comment: You have an issue somewhere else I guess. What does the onCreate look like from your Activity?

Comment: see my answer **i set button *or* background color** @kpokrywja

Comment: @MohammadAli butI want to set this and this

Comment: here is explanation of your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870443/inflateexception-with-floatingactionbutton-from-official-design-library#answer-30895974

Comment: i don't getting you what you want ?

Comment: see your question you want to change background color and set image so i provide code @kpokrywja

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatically you can change background color:

```
aBu.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)));
```

in `xml` you can use :

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
```

Or Set a Button using below code:

```
aBu.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `app:backgroundTint` .FloatingActionButton is from support library so you must use **app** namespace. **android** namespace can lead to crash or improper working

`android` is usually used for attribute coming from Android SDK itself.

`app` is often used if you are using the support library.

```
<com.smok.maps.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ikona2"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/mapview"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />
```

For setting Image try:

```
floatingActionButoon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image_name);
```

Answer (score -1):

I Hope this will work for you.

Instead of this

```
android:tint="@color/green"
```

Use

```
android:backgroundTint="#008000"
```