# Gradle: No such property for class error thrown in sub-module?

Tags: java, gradle, properties, dependencies

I am trying to declare the `dependencies` in my gradle project using the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547170/in-gradle-how-do-i-declare-common-dependencies-in-a-single-place).

However when I do so I get this error:

```
No such property: libraries for class
```

How can I fix this?

Dependencies declared as properties at top level **build.gradle** as follows:

```
ext.libraries = [


junit: 'junit:junit:4.10'

]
```

Trying to retrieve dependency in **module level build.gradle** (where error is being thrown):

```
testCompile([
              libraries.junit
])
```

**Error thrown:**

```
No such property: libraries for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

Comment: Could you please try: `project.libraries.junit`?

Comment: What is the difference with using this? I tried but I am getting the same error?

Comment: Should be the same, however sometimes it may have meaning. Do you have an online demo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: No I don't sorry, do you mean to add the "properties" prefix to the top level build.gradle, sub module, or both?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, what's the project structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your top level `settings.gradle`, include your subproject:

   ```
   include 'subproject'
   ```
2. In your top level `build.gradle` define your ext properties:

   ```
   ext.libraries = [junit: 'junit:junit:4.10']
   ```

it does not have to be a map, if you're using just 1 value, but I'm sticking with your formatting.

3. To use this in your `subproject build.gradle`:

   ```
   dependencies{
     testCompile libraries.junit 
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok, so I don't need to have "project" anywhere?

Comment: `project.ext.varname` is the fully qualified proper resolution for ext variables. Just `varname` is shorthand.