# How to correctly set Extra Properties within Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, junit, dependencies

In my top level `build.gradle` project I am attempting to add `extra properties` using the following:

```
project.ext.libraries = [

        junit: 'junit:junit:4.10'

]
```

I then attempt to reference them in a lower level `build.gradle` but get this error:

```
testCompile([
                        project.libraries.junit
])
```

However I get this error:

```
"Could not find property "libraries" for project
```

Do I need to add anything else to my Gradle code to get this to work?

Comment: Is your `ext.libraries` declaration in the `allprojects` or `subprojects` section?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: No such property for class error thrown in sub-module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338826/gradle-no-such-property-for-class-error-thrown-in-sub-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have already setup the subproject relationship properly in root `settings.gradle` using `include`, in root level build.gradle

```
ext.libraries = [junit: 'junit:junit:4.10']
```

In your subproject:

```
dependencies{
  testCompile libraries.junit
}
```

All ext properties defined in your root project are available in the sub projects.