# Gradle: What is the advantage of declaring dependencies as properties in build file?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I am trying to refactor the way that I declare my dependencies in my project.

I am currently using the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547170/in-gradle-how-do-i-declare-common-dependencies-in-a-single-place).

For example:

In top level `build.gradle` I am defining my dependency as a constant as so:

```
ext.libraries = [


junit: 'junit:junit:4.10'

]
```

Then referencing it in the sub-module `build.gradle` like so:

```
testCompile([
              libraries.junit
])
```

Is the only advantage of doing this that it saves memory?

My current understanding is that by defining a dependency in the typical Gradle way in the top level `build.gradle`, it is then added to **EVERY** sub-module.

But by defining it as a property and only referencing the property in the sub-modules that use it, you are saving memory as it is **only** added to the sub-modules that need it?

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really add dependencies in the top-level gradle file.

Declaring dependencies like this is to avoid repetition. Avoiding repetition is good when you need to change something such as the version number of your dependencies: you'll need to edit only one place for that instead of all your submodule build.gradle files.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What do you mean by "You can't really add dependencies in the top-level gradle file". Is it not possible to add dependencies to all sub-projects by declaring them at the top level? Does each sub-module not have jars attached to it that it needs?

Comment: That's correct, I think what he meant was: "you can't really add them to the top-level because they will be added to the sub-projects"